# How to toggle layers in Mapbox GL JS using React

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I am using `react-map-gl` to display a Mapbox map with several layers. I now want to let the user toggle the visibility of these layers using some kind of control panel on the map. I really like the look of the [Toggle Layers](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/) example on the Mapbox website, but it's all in vanilla JS not React.

The best example I've found [uses checkboxes to adjust layers](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/examples/layers), but it does so by using a default style with several built-in layers, modifying the JSON which defines that style, and then passing the modified JSON to the `mapStyle` property of the `Map` component. Presently, I'm using this property to point to a style I have created in Mapbox Studio:

```
<Map
    initialViewState={{
        longitude: -0.239348,
        latitude: 51.592045,
        zoom: 11.5
    }}
    style={{ width: "100%", height: 400 }}
    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapboxuser/xxxxxxxxx"
    styleDiffing
    mapboxAccessToken={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
    onMouseMove={onHover}
    interactiveLayerIds={['protectedSegments']}
>
    <Source type="geojson" data={boundaries}>
        <Layer {...boundaryStyle} />
    </Source>
    <Source type="geojson" data={majorRoads}>
        <Layer {...majorRoadsStyle} />
    </Source>
    <Source type="geojson" data={protectedSegments}>
        <Layer {...protectedSegmentStyle} />
    </Source>
</Map>
```

Obviously, that URL isn't routeable, so I couldn't for example use `fetch` on it.

And anyway, this approach seems odd, since the layers I'm adjusting have been added to the map on the client side. In fact, the [API docs](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/layer) for the `Layer` component say:

> Once a `<Layer>` is mounted, the following props should not change. If you add/remove multiple JSX layers dynamically, make sure you use React's key prop to give each element a stable identity.

The sample code doesn't seem to deal with this, since the layers that it is adjusting don't have React `<Layer>` components.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, since this is one of the most common things someone building a web map would want to do. In Leaflet, there's even a [built-in control](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/) to let you adjust the visibility of the various layer. How does one do this in `react-map-gl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `layout` property of the `<Layer>` component to adjust visibility of an individual layer. The trick, though, is that you need to provide the strings [`visible` or `none`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-fill-visibility) to the `visibility` property.

*Map.js*

```js
const [layersVisibility, setLayersVisibility] = React.useReducer(
    (state, updates) => ({ ...state, ...updates }
), {});

return (
<Map ...>
    <Source key="boundaries" type="geojson" data={boundaries}>
        <Layer key="boundaries"
            {...boundaryStyle}
            layout={{ visibility: layersVisibility["boundaries"] }} />
    </Source>
    <ControlPanel onChange={setLayersVisibility} />
</Map>
)
```

*ControlPanel.js*

```js
function ControlPanel(props) {
    const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState({
        boundaries: true,
        protectedSegments: true,
        majorRoads: true
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        // Convert true/false to "visible"/"none"
        const visibilityState = Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(visibility).map(([k, v]) => [k, v ? "visible" : "none"])
        );
        props.onChange(visibilityState);
    }, [visibility]);

    const onVisibilityChange = (name, value) => {
        setVisibility({ ...visibility, [name]: value });
    };

    return(
        <div className={styles["control-panel"]}>
            <h3>Layers</h3>
            <label><input type="checkbox"
                checked={visibility["boundaries"]}
                onChange={evt => onVisibilityChange("boundaries", evt.target.checked)}
            /> Boundaries</label>
        </div>
    )
}

export default React.memo(ControlPanel);
```